# Routing Protocol Encryption

Tags: encryption, authentication, man-in-the-middle, routing, cisco

As far as I know 'newer' versions of routing protocols support authentication between routers.

What about encryption and integrity checks? Some implementations like [this one from Cisco](http://www.informit.com/library/content.aspx?b=CCIE_Practical_Studies_I&seqNum=141) use MD5, which I dont feel secure using. How do you protect against MITM tampering with your routing tables?

Is there any easier way to protect from using IPSEC between your routers?

Comment: From what I understand OSPFv3 uses IPSEC, at least on Cisco routers and OSPFv2 only supports MD5.

Comment: MD5 is weak against collisions, but it is still pretty good against preimage attacks. If the use of MD5 is for something like an HMAC, it is plenty. I can't check how it's used, since that link is down (dammit linkrot).

Answer (score 1):

**OSPFv3** uses **IPSec** if you don't know much about **IPSec** I wrote a paragraph about it in [another answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83681/how-secure-is-l2tpipsec/186123#186123) which should give you some more information.

In Ciscos implementation of OSPFv3 they use **MD5** correct, however, it's not to keep the data safe, it's merely used as an authentication check. You can read more about OSPFv3 in [Configuring IPSec](http://topics-cdn.dell.com/s4820t_9.7.0.0_config_pub-v1-temp/en-us/GUID-02EA7417-BA74-46CB-B1CC-8F6AD47633D7.html). IPSec is pretty secure I don't think you have any reason to feel that it's not, for confidentiality of data you can use **AES-CBC 128/192** but more is in the link I provided.

I believe Cisco's implementation has thrown you off a bit as you've seen MD5 and instantly assumed "bad" however that's not the case, they're not encrypting the data with it else that would be bad.

---

Regarding people "tampering with the routing tables" I find this section to be a little unclear. If you're worried about local credentials on newer Cisco devices/versions for local credentials, you can use **Type-8** passwords, you can read more about this [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/150733/cisco-ios-service-password-encryption/186082#186082)

---

<sub>Just to add to this Forest's comment on it being used as an [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) is correct.</sub>