# How secure is L2TP+IPSEC?

Tags: vpn, ipsec

I understand PPTP is widely used still, but insecure. A convenient alternative is: L2TP+IPSEC.

How secure is it?

What steps in the server setup can I take to maintain a high degree of compatibility with Windows 7+ and OSX clients and still maintain strong security? For example, defining what encryption algorithms are available such as blowfish, aes-256 and 3des, DH-Group options etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**PPTP** is incredibly insecure as you've stated and provides next to no security whatsoever, there are tons of vulnerabilities in it and should be avoided at all costs. You can read more about those vulnerabilities [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Tunneling_Protocol) if you scroll down to [Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Tunneling_Protocol#Security)

---

**L2TP** should always obviously be used with **IPSec** because **L2TP** doesn't actually feature **any** encryption if you run it as a standalone, which is why you will mostly see it paired with **IPSec**.

---

**IPSec** tends to be pretty secure. Below is a list of the Cryptographic algorithms it uses:

- Authenticity & Integrity Protection: **HMAC-SHA1/SHA2**
- Confidentiality: **3DES-CBC** it can also use **AES-CBC** and **AES-GCM**. It is worth noting that **AES-GCM** will also perform authentication, so that could be a reason for choosing it.

**IPSec** will also perform a **Diffie Hellman** exchange before data is ever sent across a link.

You can refer to [RFC7321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7321) to learn more about **IPSec**, [here](https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/security-documents/encryption-in-ipsec/ta-p/3136249) is a very, exceptional article on the Cisco forums on how it works, I'd highly recommend reading it as it goes into a lot more detail than my post.